# Styling select dropdowns without losing the arrow

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have the following [html/CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/Q656m/)

This works great except I lose my arrow in chrome. I tried removing the

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

From the select I lose my formatting on the options (except for the one initially shown).

**Update**

I thought my sentence above illustrated this but this is not acceptable

[image: wrong]

Comment: You'd have to share your test site to show what formatting are you losing because as far as I can see, it still works great after removing `-webkit-appearance: none;`

Comment: You aren't looking at the options you are looking at the select

Comment: I've updated my answer to better address your question. Does it answer everything you need to know, or is there something else I can help with?

Answer (score 1):

You are wanting to style the `option` along with the `select`. Unfortunately, nearly all browsers strictly limit the styling of `options` to maintain consistency. An odd oversight on their part, but it is what it is. Here are some options (pun intended) that you have:

1: Use a hidden `input` and a javascript dropdown menu. Probably using `ul` and `li` to replicate the `select` and `option`.

2: Use a jQuery plugin. There are several.

http://patrickkunka.github.io/easydropdown/

http://uniformjs.com/

http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/dropdown

Comment: Did you check the drop down? the options are still wrong

Comment: Given you had to do an update to clarify, I don't think it deserves a downvote. Anyway, I'm looking into a fix now that I understand what you are really asking.

Comment: I only added i didn't edit this sentance was still there "From the select I lose my formatting on the options (except for the one initially shown)." I appreciate the solutions I will look into them.

Comment: I know, I just said update, because that is the word that you used in the second comment. If I gave the wrong impression, then I apologize. The original mistake was mine for misreading your original question.

Comment: I tried uniform and it doesn't seem to work (the options are still the same) I will try a couple of the others but if you get the jfiddle to work just let me know.

Comment: Implementing a library will take a bit, but I'll see if I can get it working in a Fiddle tonight.